# class derivation problem

Tags: c#, generics, class, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have the following 3 classes:

```
class Node {
    public Node Parent;

    // Edit: to clarify, each of these classes has many fields and methods
    public void Method1() { /*...*/ }
    public void Method2() { /*...*/ }
    /* ... */
    public void Method30() { /*...*/ }
}
class Element : Node { public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes; }
class Document : Element { }
```

I need to have a way to define `ExtraNode`, `ExtraElement` and `ExtraDocument` so that they are the equivalent of copying the code above, adding a few extra fields to the `Node` class, and prefixing all classes with "Extra", like so:

```
class ExtraNode { public Node Parent; public int Priority; }
class ExtraElement : ExtraNode { public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes; }
class ExtraDocument : ExtraElement { }
```

What is the best to achieve this? I thought about interfaces (`ExtraNode : Node, IExtra`), but then `(ExtraElement is ExtraNode) == false`.

I also thought about rewriting the classes as generics (`Node<T>, Element<T>, Document<T>`), then using them to define the new classes (`ExtraNode : Node<MyExtraClass>` and so on), but it still leads to the problem of `(ExtraElement is ExtraNode) == false` because `(Element<MyExtraClass> is Node<MyExtraClass>) == false`.

So what is the best way of achieving this, without copy / pasting the entire document and changing by hand? I will need to do this more than once.

**Edit:** to clarify what I need to be able to do, I need the following code to work:

```
// this should accept an ExtraNode, an ExtraElement or an ExtraDocument:
void doSomethingWithANode(ExtraNode extraNode) { ... }
```

**Edit 2:** Kirk's suggestion about implementing interfaces (as exemplified by Timwi's code) is impractical in my case because each class has many fields and methods (and there are about 8 classes in total), so I would have to copy each and every one of them for each 'Extra' derivate group. For example this is how the Node classes would look:

```
class INode {
    INode Parent { get; }
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
    /* ... */
    void Method30();
}

class ExtraNode {
    public int Priority { get; } // extra
    public INode Parent { get; } // THIS IS WRONG, THIS SHOULD BE ExtraNode NOT INode
    public void Method1() { ... } // here I have to define the entire method
    public void Method2() { ... }
    /* ... */
    public void Method30() { ... }
}

class SuperNode {
    public string Superpower { get; } // extra
    public INode Parent { get; } // THIS IS WRONG, THIS SHOULD BE SuperNode NOT INode
    public void Method1() { ... } // here I have to define the entire method AGAIN
    public void Method2() { ... } // all methods are identical to the ones in ExtraNode
    /* ... */
    public void Method30() { ... } // this is unnecessary code duplication
}
```

So 30 methods are duplicated every single time. And this applies for all the other classes. By this method I would duplicate so much, I'm practically duplicating all the code. It would be easier to simply copy / paste the entire class, rename and add the extra fields to them.

Comment: If you used interfaces, then you'd presumably have IExtraNode, IExtraElement, and IExtraDocument.  ExtraElement would be defined as ExtraElement: Element, IExtraElement, and IExtraElement would be defined as IExtraElement: IExtraNode.  With this setup, (ExtraElement is IExtraNode) == true.

Comment: @Kirk thanks for the suggestion, but what I need is ExtraElement to be as ExtraNode, not IExtraNode. To illustrate, I need to be able to do: ExtraNode = someExtraElement ?? someExtraNode.

Comment: Right, so if you were to actually use interfaces, you would probably want to use them properly and consistently.  In other words, you would no longer wish to declare ExtraNode/ExtraElement/etc. as their concrete types -- all your variables would always be typed to the interface.  Then, since "ExtraNode" would be of type IExtraNode, you could do:  ExtraNode = someExtraElement ?? someExtraNode.

Comment: @Kirk but then the interfaces would have nothing to with Node/Element/Document. They'd only have the Extra stuff. I of course need the objects to have both the fields from Node/Element/Document and Extra.

Comment: I'm not sure you have control over the Node/Element/Document classes.  If you don't, you're out of luck.  If you do, you should create INode/IElement/IDocument interfaces that those classes implement.  Then your "IExtra" versions would all extend those base interfaces.  And from there you should be in business.

Comment: I do have control over them, however creating the extra interfaces would mean I would have to rewrite every single method and all properties of each of these 3 classes (there are about 8 in total in the full code). I might as well copy the entire thing, and it would actually mean less code.

Answer (score 1):

I think Kirk Woll’s idea in the comments is pretty much the best option. I ran into a similar problem in my code, and I came up with the same idea. What you really want to be able to do is have an inheritance tree with multiple inheritance, and in C# only interfaces allow you this.

```
public interface INode { public INode Parent { get; } }
public interface IElement : INode { public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; } }
public interface IDocument : IElement { ... }

public interface IExtraNode : INode { public int Priority { get; } }
public interface IExtraElement : IExtraNode, IElement { }
public interface IExtraDocument : IExtraElement, IDocument { ... }
```

Now all the properties you wanted are true:

```
element is INode                // check
document is IElement            // check
extraNode is INode              // check
extraElement is INode           // check
extraElement is IExtraNode      // check
extraDocument is IExtraElement  // check
extraDocument is IElement       // check
extraDocument is INode          // check
```

**Responding to your Edit #2:** Yes, you would have to duplicate *some* of the implementations, but not many. In particular, you don’t need to duplicate anything in `ExtraNode` (you can just inherit from `Node`). If the “extra” stuff is not much, you can duplicate only the extra stuff, i.e. inherit `ExtraElement` from `Element` (instead of from `ExtraNode`) etc.

Regarding the problem you mentioned here:

```
public INode Parent { get; } // THIS IS WRONG, THIS SHOULD BE ExtraNode NOT INode
```

I believe this should be `IExtraNode`. You can solve this by using an explicitly-implemented property (I’m assuming now that you’re *not* deriving `ExtraNode` from `Node`, but only to illustrate the solution):

```
// Real code goes here
public IExtraNode Parent { get { return ...; } }

// This calls the property above, and implements the interface property
public INode INode.Parent { get { return Parent; } }
```

**Yet another edit:** You could also declare a class called `Extra` which contains all the extra functionality, and have `ExtraNode`, `ExtraElement` and `ExtraDocument` all have a field of type `Extra`. You could either make this field public, or you could write one-line redirect methods for all its functionality. This is truly a minimum of duplication, given the lack of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a [mixin-like](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/02/c-quasi-mixins-pattern.html) construct to share the necessary code:

```
interface MNode {
  MNode Parent { get; }
}
static class MNodeCode {
  public static void Method1(this MNode self) { /*...*/ }
  public static void Method2(this MNode self) { /*...*/ }
  /* ... */
  public static void Method30(this MNode self) { /*...*/ }
}

class Node : MNode {
  public Node Parent { get { ... } }
  MNode MNode.Parent { get { return Parent; } }
}
class Element : Node { public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes; }
class Document : Element { }

class ExtraNode : MNode {
  public ExtraNode Parent { get { ... } }
  MNode MNode.Parent { get { return Parent; } }
}
class ExtraElement : ExtraNode { public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes; }
class ExtraDocument : ExtraElement { }
```

You can create different mixins to get a different sharing granularity.